# Bootstrap column layout and ordering (push/pull?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to layout a web page using bootstrap with two columns containing elements of various heights.

When above `sm` I want to layout to be in two columns as below:

*easy when `a` and `b` are in the same div with `c` separate*

[image: dual column]

But when `sm` and below I want div `c` to shift in between `a` and `b` like this:

*easy when `a` `c` and `b` are in that order*

[image: single column]

*Note*: `b` should sit directly below `a` and **NOT** be influenced by the height of `c`. As the divs are different heights, I'm having trouble aligning div `b` when div `a` is short and div `c` is long.

Comment: could you take advantage of `hidden` and `visible` bootstrap classes to hide and show `c` in a different location? (would require the html to be in two places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `pull-right` class on the middle block. Following `HTML` structure will make it possible.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.red {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.green {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffa500;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="red">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 pull-right">
      <div class="green">c</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="yellow">b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning to "pull" C over to the right at the screen size you wish using a media query

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/52/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div id="divA">A</div>
      <div id="divC">C</div>
      <div id="divB">B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#divA,
#divB,
#divC{
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  width:100%;
}

#divA{
  background:red;
}

#divB{
  background:orange;
}

#divC{
  background: green;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #divC{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
  }
}
```